# PowerShell zip file extraction catching exceptons

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I am having the following code in Power Shell ( windows Server 2016 TP3 )

```
$zipFrom = Get-Item($zipfilepath);
$destTo=Get-Item($destination)
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfrom,$destTo)
```

The problem is that I get the dreaded 260 character file limit error . The question is how do i ignore error and continue with the extraction ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunate it is not possible. Instead of you can use free 7-zip which can handle above problem.

The code could be:

```
set-alias 7zip "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

$zipFrom = Get-Item($zipfilepath);
$destTo=Get-Item($destination)
7zip x $zipfrom -o"$destTo"
```